# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent custom sizes and get_intermediate_image_sizes()

Tags: wp-query, headers

When adding custom sizes and returning `get_intermediate_image_sizes();` throws the error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`. The entire code is:

```
<?php
function mt_custom_image_size() {
        // Create some new image sizes
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        add_image_size('1140w', 1140, 0);
        add_image_size('1024w', 1024, 0);
        add_image_size('960w', 960, 0);
        add_image_size('800w', 800, 0);
        add_image_size('768w', 768, 0);
        add_image_size('640w', 640, 0);
        add_image_size('425w', 425, 0);
        add_image_size('320w', 320, 0);
    }
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mt_custom_image_size' );

function mt_post_query() {
        
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'posts_per_page' => '1',
            'paged'          => '1',
            'fields'         => 'ids',
        );
        
        $post_query = get_posts( $args );
        
        if  ( ! empty( $post_query ) ) {
      
            $registered_image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
            
            echo '<pre>';
                print_r( $registered_image_sizes );
            echo '</pre>';
            
            foreach( $post_query as $post_id ) {
                 
                $image_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );
                            
                echo '<pre>';
                    print_r( $image_meta );
                echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'mt_post_query', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

The error occurs when `print_r( $image_meta );` is called. The message displayed is `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/mt/functions.php:43) in /home/site/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9`

If I remove all the custom sizes, the error disappears. I can't for the life of me figure out why it's returning the warning. There is no other code in the `functions.php` file.

Comment: You’ve already found the cause. You cannot print any output from within this hook.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, thanks. Do you have any suggestions on how best to print any output without the error occurring or is it a case of you can't print it at all?

Comment: You can’t print any output before the headers are sent without causing this error. If you want information from debugging then just ignore the error or use error_log to write the information to the error log.